# How to load the MainActivity on pressing the Back button of the Phone

Tags: android, back-button

I have a `MainActivity` that has a `NavigationDrawer` in it.In the menu of the drawer each item starts a new activity.Now when i press the Back button from any of these activities i end up in a blank page,when i press it again it goes to main activity.What i want is to go directly to the main activity.

my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.defcomm.invento;

import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.defcomm.invento.NavigationDrawerActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class INVENTO extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinator;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsableLayout;
private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
private ViewPager mPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    mCoordinator= (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
    mCollapsableLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mCollapsableLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    nestedScrollView= (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.rvToDoList);
    mCollapsableLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedTitleTextAppearence);
    mCollapsableLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
    NavigationDrawerActivity drawerFragment= (NavigationDrawerActivity) getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout), toolbar);


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_invento, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

my `NavigationDrawer.java1`:

```
package com.defcomm.invento;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.clickListener {

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mdrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mdrawerLayout;
private boolean mUserLearnedState;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private CoordinatorLayout mcoordinator;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
View containerId;
public static final String file_pref_name = "Testpef";
public static final String KEY_USER_VALUE = "user_learned_drawer";
private boolean mfromSavedInstanceState;

public NavigationDrawerActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedState = Boolean.valueOf(readPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_VALUE, "false"));
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mfromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    adapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(),getdata());
    adapter.setClicklistener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return layout;

}
public static List<ListItems> getdata(){
    List<ListItems> nav_data=new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons={R.drawable.variable,R.drawable.ignore};
    String[] texts={"Coding","Hacking"};
    for(int i=0;i<icons.length&&i<icons.length;i++){
        ListItems current=new ListItems();
        current.iconId=icons[i];
        current.IconName=texts[i];
        nav_data.add(current);
    }
    return nav_data;
}

public void setUp(final int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerlayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    mdrawerLayout = drawerlayout;
    containerId = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mdrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerlayout, toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!mUserLearnedState) {
                mUserLearnedState = true;
                saveToPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_VALUE, mUserLearnedState + "");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if (slideOffset < 0.5f) {
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
            }
        }
    };
    if (!mUserLearnedState && !mfromSavedInstanceState) {
        mdrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerId);
    }

    mdrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mdrawerToggle);
    mdrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mdrawerToggle.syncState();

        }
    });

}


public static void saveToPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences(file_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences share = context.getSharedPreferences(file_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return share.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
}

@Override
public void ItemCLick(View view, int position) {
    if(position==0){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Coding.class));
    }
    if(position==1){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Hacking.class));
    }

  }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.defcomm.invento" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".INVENTO"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Coding"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coding" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Hacking"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hacking" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You could at least check that your MainActivity is set as the parent activity for the other Activities that are started from the NavigationDrawer. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html). And maybe post your AndroidManifest.xml here as well as it may have something else relevant to the problem. Also have you overridden onBackPressed() in the other Activities? If yes, how? And finally do you mean the back button at the bottom or in the Action Bar?

Comment: By back button i mean the physical button of the phone.Since i 'm new to android , i would like to know how to set the main activity as the parent activity of other activity. And for the `AndroidManifest.xml` i 'm editing the post here.Thankyou.

Comment: My guess would be that your code adds an empty fragment (or activity) to back stack. Maybe you don't see this when your app starts because your loading fragments or another activity right in an `onSomething` lifecycle method. But when you go back you see it. Also, rename `NavigationDrawerActivity` to `NavigationDrawerFragment` because it is a fragment not an activity.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but is there any reason why we have to do this? Shouldn't it be automatically set to start the parent activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This will close all other activities and start MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

This will close the drawer when it's open and back is pressed rather than taking you back to the previous activity (or exiting).

```
DrawerLayout drawer...

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this , MainActivity.class))
    finish();

    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```